# How do I compare two dates in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am creating a Green Pass app and I need some info.
I use Kotlin with this code:

```
val expirationTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond (map [CwtHeaderKeys.EXPIRATION.asCBOR ()]. AsInt64 ())
verificationResult.isNotExpired = expirationTime.isAfter (Instant.now ())
```

I should check between the certificate date and today's date, if it exceeds 45 days it opens a new activity for me.

Comment: Couldn't you just calculate the difference of your dates and check if the difference is greater than  3.888.000 (45 days in seconds) and if it is greater open the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`

Example to find number of days between two dates:

```kotlin
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2)
```

You can use the same mechanisem for other time units:

```kotlin
ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(date1, date2)
```

Get the result and check if its greater then 45.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.time.Duration`

```
val days = Duration.between(expirationTime, Instant.now()).toDays()
if (days > 45) {
   // your actions
}
```

Comment: @GiuseppeEDP yes

Comment: Ok, i have a problem. 
If i put code on DefaultCborService not import element

https://i.imgur.com/WyW4Fnk.png

Comment: @GiuseppeEDP i didn't understand anything from your picture. Try putting a better example in your original Question

Comment: I would need a popup warning me when the date exceeds 45 days, the code is this:

val issuedAt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(map[CwtHeaderKeys.ISSUED_AT.asCBOR()].AsInt64())
            verificationResult.isIssuedTimeCorrect = issuedAt.isBefore(Instant.now())